# How to speed up deleting documents without rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, notin

document headers are in omdok table:

```
create table omdok ( dokumnr serial primary key, ... );
```

document rows are in omrid table

```
CREATE TABLE omrid
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  reanr serial NOT NULL,
  dokumnr integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT omrid_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT omrid_dokumnr_fkey FOREIGN KEY (dokumnr)
      REFERENCES omdok (dokumnr) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE,
  ....
);
```

Records in omdok which do not have child rows in omrid needs to be deleted

I tried

```
delete from omdok where dokumnr not in      (select dokumnr from omrid)
```

Query it is running currently 15 hours and is still running. postgres.exe is using 50% CPU  all the time (this is 2 core CPU).

```
explain delete from omdok where dokumnr not in      (select dokumnr from omrid)
```

returns:

```
"Delete  (cost=0.00..21971079433.34 rows=220815 width=6)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on omdok  (cost=0.00..21971079433.34 rows=220815 width=6)"
"        Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))"
"        SubPlan 1"
"          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..94756.92 rows=1897261 width=4)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on omrid  (cost=0.00..77858.61 rows=1897261 width=4)"
```

- How to delete parents without child rows fast?
- Will this command finish or is postgres hanging ?
- Currently it is running 15 hours. How many hours it takes to finish ?
  How to speed up this query ?

Using

```
PostgreSQL 9.0.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 64-bit

Windows 2003 x64 server with 4 GB RAM.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is to simply create an index on `omrid(dokumnr)`:

```
create index idx_omrid_dokumnr on omrid(dokumnr);
```

This should speed the processing of the `not in` in your original query.

Comment: psql-genral mailing list recommends to replace it with `delete from omdok where not exists(select 1 from omrid where omdok.dokumnr = omrid.dokumnr);`

Comment: @Andrus . . . I do prefer the `not exists` as well, but I think the index will work for either formulation.

Answer (score 1):

You do not qualify your `DELETE` query in any way so the 220,815 documents are compared against the 1,897,261 document rows. That will take time.

The simplest optimization is using a `DISTINCT` clause on the document rows, which should bring the rows from `omrid` down by a factor 8 or so:

```
DELETE FROM omdok WHERE dokumnr NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT dokumnr FROM omrid);
```

A potentially faster solution is to first identify the documents without rows, then delete those rows:

```
WITH docs0rows AS (
  SELECT dokumnr
  FROM omdok d
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT dokumnr FROM omrid) dr ON dr.dokumnr = d.dokumnr
  WHERE dr.dokumnr IS NULL
)
DELETE FROM omdok d
USING docs0rows zero
WHERE d.dokumnr = zero.dokumnr;
```

Disclaimer: Test this command before you run it to see which rows will be deleted.

Comment: it causes error column reference "dokumnr" is ambiguous. Probably omdok.dokumnr should used in delete where clauset. Will using clause work in 9.0 or should it moved to from ?

Comment: In the `DELETE` statement you use `USING` instead of `FROM` to specify additional tables to build conditional clauses for filtering. Works in all versions. Answer corrected.

Comment: Why aliases d and zero are used in delete ? is it safe to remove them and use table names instead ?